# Select option from javascript span with python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to generate a bot to automatically make orders from walmart, but it seems like I just can't get selected the color and the quantity, since they are not really selectors and they have no id.
I'm working with python and selenium.

The item using for tests right now is this one:
https://www.walmart.com/ip/8-x10-Picture-Frames-Set-of-6/10404226

About the quantity I think I was able to select the list with:

```
quantity = walmart.find_element_by_css_selector("span.product-quantity-dropdown-wrapper")
```

but after that I just can't select the quantity.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you considered using the [Walmart API](https://developer.walmartlabs.com/)?

Comment: I think walmart API is only for querys, not for actually purchasing

Comment: Read the [docs](https://developer.walmartlabs.com/docs). In the response shown, there are keys entitled `productUrl`, `addToCartUrl`, and others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as `quantity` goes, you can operate *the actual `select` element* (via the [`Select` class](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select)) which is not visually detected, but is actually visible. As for the color, you can *dynamically construct an XPath expression* to locate the color "by name".

Complete working implementation (selects white color and quantity = 2):

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.walmart.com/ip/8-x10-Picture-Frames-Set-of-6/10404226")

color = "White"
quantity = 2

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# select color
color_selector = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class = 'variant-swatch' and @title='{color}']/..".format(color=color))))
color_selector.click()

# harcode delay - see if you can avoid it
time.sleep(0.5)

# select quantity
quantity_selector = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "WMItemQtyDropDown")))
quantity_selector = Select(quantity_selector)
quantity_selector.select_by_value(str(quantity))
```

That said, make sure you are not violating any Terms of Use and staying on the legal side. Make sure to explore the [Walmart API](https://developer.walmartlabs.com/) as well (see @MattDMo's comment).